# SQLObject: reusing my arguments list

Tags: python, dry, sqlobject

I'm using SQLObject and I've got the following:

```
# update foo if it exists, otherwise create a new one
if self.foo_exists:
  Foo.get(foo_id).set(name = foo['name'], ip = foo['ip'], port = foo['port'], mode = foo['mode'], max_conn = foo['max_conn']) 
else:
  Foo(name = foo['name'], ip = foo['ip_address'], port = foo['port'], mode = foo['mode'], max_conn = foo['max_conn'])
```

It works well, but I'd really like to remove the duplication. I'm passing the exact same arguments to `Foo()` as I am to `.set()`.

I tried passing a dict but SQLObject doesn't support that.

Answer (score 1):

```
try:
    obj = Foo.get(foo_id)
    obj.set(**d)
except SQLObjectNotFound:
    Foo(**d)
```

It supports dict, use **dict. It is also a duplicate, but not so loud.